# find: missing argument to `-exec' on VM Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, command-line-interface

I am facing an issue on this command line

```
sh.exec('find site/docs/4.1/examples/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "rtl-*" - 
exec bash -c \'rm -rf site/docs/4.1/examples/$(basename "{}")/*\; rmdir 
site/docs/4.1/examples/$(basename "{}")\' ;',(code))
```

which raises a ***find: missing argument to `-exec'***

I am troubleshooting it with everything I found on the internet but none of the fix found help me.
do you have an idea why it's not working ?

Comment: I believe it should be `-exec bash -c ...`, not `exec bash -c ...`. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Thank you jww. But it's no working for me :/

Comment: Hello !
I solved it by adding a double backslash before the last semicolon of the command line.
`sh.exec('find site/docs/4.1/examples/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name \'rtl-*\' -exec bash -c \'rm -rf site/docs/4.1/examples/$(basename "{}")/* ; rmdir site/docs/4.1/examples/$(basename "{}")\'\\ ;' `